# Multiple docker images from SBT

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using `sbt native packager` to generate `docker image` for `Spray` API application. Code is just simplest version from [tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html). Now I'd like to reuse some case classes and create job process loading data in my backend.

> parent project
>   * common protocol
>   * API
>   * Job

How to generate two `docker images` from one project?

Comment: It's not possible to do with `DockerPlugin`.

Comment: Just found it is possible, will post update here (promise)

Comment: @expert please check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal example can be found in this [repo](https://github.com/ppiotrow/sbt-multi-docker-example).

The answer is that you could enable `DockerPlugin` in each project module you want to generate Docker image for.